# javascript find string function

Tags: javascript, string, find

I need to implement a simp^le "find" function which will retrieve the 1st occurence of a given string, then find next occurrences on demand.

Please no jQuery, only good plain javascript.

Comment: I googled a bit, but only found old or rubbish code. I hope someone here will supply a simple and elegant solution!

Comment: by find, do you mean the first occurrence within a whole page? or the first occurrence of a string within a given string?

Comment: Why don't you google exactly what the title of your post is, then click the first result. I did that and found the solution right there. How did you "google a bit" and not come up with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `window.find()` that the browser offers.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find) for more info.

```
window.find(aString, aCaseSensitive, aBackwards, aWrapAround,
        aWholeWord, aSearchInFrames, aShowDialog);
```

This is supported in Firefox and WebKit.  For IE, there is a work-around [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm) using the `findText()` method of a `TextRange` object.